# bad CPU type in executable: pip error in mac command line

Tags: macos, terminal, pip, pipenv, python-venv

Tried  to enter "pip install --user pipenv" in the command line on mac but it invokes the message from the title all the time, although, my shell is set to this /bin/zsh